# How to speed up search in MySQL table (No Index)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a site (MLM) where there are around 155000 rows in "memberdata" table with 63 column.
All member searches frequently from that table for different Data.
my SQL query is like:

```
$search=htmlentities($_POST['search_field']); /// The field which will be selected
$value=htmlentities($_POST['search_value']); /// The value which will be compared
SELECT * FROM memberdata WHERE $search='$value' AND (senior='".$_SESSION['id']."' OR id > '".$_SESSION['id']."')
```

But no field is indexed except "id". "id" is "PRIMARY with AUTO_INCREMENT".

My query is takes too long time and sometime shows "maximum server execution time 30 sec exceeded" etc.
what should I do? how can I make my query faster without indexing ? i'm on Apache server at shared host.

Comment: Can you give the structure of the *memberdata* table?

Comment: You should at least add an index on `senior`. Otherwise a full scan of the table is to happen 100%.

Comment: a table with 63 columns does not seems to be   good way to expand . the best he you can enclosed your table design

Comment: In addition, having about 60 columns that all can used for searching is a problem, too.

Comment: I understand that indexing may help me. But in MLM project there one senior can be of 100 downline, so in senior field I can't add primary or unique index. so what can I do. Also I can leave maximum 10 field but other 53 field is must to show in profile page. please help me. I can give the database structure.

Answer (score 8):

Why you don't want to add indexes? You can always do some tricks to fasten things up but it would **never** be as fast as an index.

As for answering your actual answer, you can try to narrow as far as you can the search in the database by removing the unnecessary fields from the `SELECT` / `WHERE` clauses. Or try to do many smaller queries instead of a big one... I'm afraid you will have to try some solutions and then do some benchmarking on them to select the best one for your setup.

But adding indexes is way simpler and faster (but will not fix magically a bad database design / bad application).

Comment: I'm guessing they are nervous about storage space. But I agree, indexing is the way to go.

Comment: also with that many records writes are not frequent so index building shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I understand that indexing may help me. But in MLM project there one senior can be of 100 downline, so in senior field I can't add primary or unique index. so what can I do. Also I can leave maximum 10 field but other 53 field is must to show in profile page. please help me. I can give the database structure.

Comment: @Indian Girl You can add a "regular" (non-unique) index. You know indexed values aren't always unique and that's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Why not select the fields you need instead of all of them? you won't need the field that auto increments. The more things you leave out of your search the quicker the search will become because that is a lot less data it has to go through.